# Unable to Detect Error through Build Definition

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild, build-definition

I Have created a build definition for ASP.net core 2.2 application on .sln file,
i intensionally commited wrong code which i will get build error in visual studio 2017, but when build definition is run build task it is not showing any error and build is also passing ....please help me

following picture are my build definition

[image: Build Definition 1]
[image: Build Definition 2]
[image: Build Definition 3]
[image: Build Definition 4]
[image: Build Definition 5]
[image: Build Definition 6]
[image: Build Definition 7]

Comment: What do the *logs* say?

Comment: @DanielMann -> No Errors, it says build succeded

Comment: Your build definition looks ok according to the shared screenshot. Have you make sure tfs and local Vs build the latest and same version of your code? And what kind of error  you get in Visual Studio 2017? One possibility, you local VS not restored the package properly.

Comment: Hello @PatrickLu-MSFT when i was trying to build the solution with false code in VS 2017 i can see build error, but in build definition there is no build error instead it is showing build success and there is no problem from package.

Comment: Hi Hulk, understand your concern. But sounds really weird. In most case, build succeed in local and failed in TFS. Actually TFS build just invoke Visual Studio  or msbuild command line in the remote build agent, just as same as build in local. Suggest you remote to the build agent and manually build the solution, then compare the result with your local build. This will help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Hi Hulk  any new info to share here? Did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested above?

Comment: Hi, @PatrickLu-MSFT sorry for late reply, i have done what you suggested then i escalated to my senior, as of now there is no proper solution. Once i get it, i will post here that solution.